# Strange behavior of bash and SIGTERM with Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, kill, trap, sigterm

Here's what happens in Ubuntu (Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-53-generic #47~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 13:10:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, *bash* 4.4.20(1)):

In Terminal, open a window (let's call it "window_1") and type:

`trap "echo something;" SIGTERM`

then

`echo $$`

**9781**

then

`kill -TERM $$`

as expected, **something** is printed in window_1 and the window stays open.

Now open another "window_2" and type:

`kill -TERM 9781`

and window_1 is closed (no time to see whether **something** is printed).

Do the same with SIGINT and everything works as expected.

Do the same with SIGUSR1 and everything works as expected, but only after the Enter key is pressed. 
Also, in *macOS 10.13.6* everything works as expected (with SIGTERM, SIGINT and SIGUSR1).

Is anybody able to explain this apparent anomaly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you using the same shell on MacOS as on Ubuntu?

Comment: No, macOS was bash version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)

Comment: The answer is that it is a quirk in the way that the readline library handles signals stemming from the fact that some terminal emulators (used to) send `TERM` instead of `HUP` to terminate the shell. See duplicate question and Chris' email conversation with the `bash` maintainer at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-03/msg00006.html with regards to that.

Comment: I suspected something of the kind, but isn't it strange that, being SIGTERM caught, the terminate action happens anyway? I checked the state of the signal after the handler installation with

`cat /proc/$$/status | grep SigCgt`

and I got 

`SigCgt: 000000004b817efb`

Which, being SIGTERM number 15, means SIGTERM is definitely handled.